# How do I retarget a VS2017 solution in VS2015?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

MSB8020
The build tools for v141 (Platform Toolset = 'v141') cannot be found. To build using the v141 build tools, please install v141 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution".

I have been working on a project in VS2017 at home, but the school computer uses VS2015. How do I retarget my solution to an older version?

I have checked the Project menu and right-clicked on both the solution and the separate projects in the solution explorer, but there is no 'Retarget solution' option.

Comment: Rightclick on the project in the Solution Explorer, select "General" under "Configuration Properies", click on "Platform Toolset" and choose "Visual Studio 2015 (v140)".

Comment: Unrelated but when I when I did this about a month ago the MS Test framework was not working properly when you retarget to v140.

Comment: Rightclick on the project in the Solution Explorer, select "General" under "Configuration Properies", click on "Platform Toolset" and choose "Visual Studio 2015 (v140)"

Michael Walz, that solved the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. Right click on the project in the Solution Explorer
2. Click on "**Properties**"
3. Navigate to "**Configuration properties**"
4. Click on the "**General**" option below "Configuration properties"
5. Change "**Platform toolset**" to *Visual Studio 2015 (v140)*

Comment: Need to also change Target Platform Version in the same page.

Comment: For whatever reason I don't have a general option here.

Comment: Make sure you clicked on the project and not the solution itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many projects within solution and there is no `Retarget solution` retargeting each one may be tedious, if you want to retarget them all at once when then:

1. Open `Property manager` from `View` menu.
2. In property manager use `SHIFT + left click` to select all projects at once.
3. Right click anywhere on the highlighted area and select `Properties`
4. In property pages that appear select `All configurations` and `All platforms` from 2 drop down lists at the top.
5. Under `Configuration properties -> general` set `Platform toolset` to desired toolset and click `OK`

Answer (score -2):

Open Visual Studio Solution file in notepad or any editor and then update the VisualStudioVersion  to 14.0.25420.1 and save the solution. Also check the MinimumVisualStudioVersion.